# Accessing parent from UserControl in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

From inside a UserControl I'm trying to reference a method on its parent.

```
public partial class Tab3_2Data : UserControl
{   
    public Tab3_2Data()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //MainPage mp = this.Ancestors().OfType<MainPage>().FirstOrDefault();
        //var x = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
        //var z = this.Parent;
        //var parent = this.Ancestors().Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        // None of the above work.. all come back as null

        // Trying to access this method on the parent
        //ShowMessage("test", OperationStatus.Green);
```

Have tried [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx) yet nothing

and

```
    // only available OOB
    //mainPage = System.Windows.Application.Current.RootVisual as MainPage;
```

UserControl being called like:

```
 <!-- Tab 3_2 -->
 <controls:TabItem Header="Groups and Roles">
     <UserControls:Tab3_2Data />
 </controls:TabItem>
```

EDIT2:
This is how I got it working:

In the UserControl:

```
UserControl x:Class="xyz.ClientApp.UserControls.Tab3_2Data" Loaded="Tab3_2Data_OnLoaded"
```

then in code behind:

```
private void Tab3_2Data_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mp = this.Ancestors().OfType<MainPage>().FirstOrDefault();
            //mp.ShowMessage("test", OperationStatus.Green);
        }
```

which uses the VisualTreeEnumeration helper class referenced in link above.

```
 public static class VisualTreeEnumeration
    {
        public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root, int depth)
        {
            int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
                yield return child;
                if (depth > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var descendent in Descendents(child, --depth))
                        yield return descendent;
                }
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root)
        {
            return Descendents(root, Int32.MaxValue);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Ancestors(this DependencyObject root)
        {
            DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(root);
            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current;
                current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the parent will only be available when the control is loaded. You can try to run this logic in a handler for the UserControl.Loaded event.
In addition, as the control is child of a TabItem, it will only be loaded when the TabItem is visible.